# Is there a way to open a form chosen at runtime in Visual Basic WFA

Tags: vb.net, winforms

On my main page I have a button which takes an input and checks it against a list of forms that currently exist, I want to be able to open the inputted form, is this possible?

So far I have tried

```
Private Sub Btn_Navigate_To_Entered_Page_Number_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Navigate_To_Entered_Page_Number.Click
    Dim targetPage
    targetPage = InputBox("Please enter the target page")
    If lst_All_Pages.Contains(targetPage) Then
        Dim Frm = New Form()
        Frm = targetPage
        Frm.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Form not found")
    End If
```

and

```
Private Sub Btn_Navigate_To_Entered_Page_Number_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Navigate_To_Entered_Page_Number.Click
Dim namespaceName As String
namespaceName = NEAStockPageSystem.sla '''This is the name of my file
Dim targetPage As String
    targetPage = InputBox("Please enter the target page")
    If lst_All_Pages.Contains(targetPage) Then
    var frm= Activator.CreateInstance(namespaceName, targetPage) as Form;
    frm.Show()
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong but neither works at all

Answer (score 0):

for your first option you are creating a blank form and then replacing it with a string and strings don't `Show`

i would suggest replacing with a simple select case

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    SelectForm(CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem).Show()
End Sub

Private Function SelectForm(value As String) As Form

    Select Case value
        Case "Form1"
            Return New Form1
        Case "Form2"
            Return New Form2
        Case "Form3"
            Return New Form3
        Case Else
            Return New Form()
    End Select
End Function
```

if you have existing forms you can return them instead of creating new,

PS as a form has to be created in your code so you should always know what the possible options are so free text is a bad idea

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I was scared that might be the only option lol
Is there any way to add new forms without adding a new case? (eg; input box for formname and if found *formname*.show()

Comment: not sure why you are worried about adding new cases, if you are creating a new form then the adding a new case is a minor factor.  however looking at your use-case i would suggest that you are more likely to be using the same form over and over again but with different data which is a much different proposition